# How to get AWS Lambda function to push Message Attributes SNS Topic destination

Tags: aws-lambda

Scenario: I have a Lambda with a SNS destination. If I "return" an object with property `MessageAttributes` it gets contained in the "responsePayload`object which also gets contained into the`Message` object.

I want to return MessageAttributes to the SNS destination from a lambda function.

Example (remember SNS is the destination):

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  
  const topicMsg = {
    Message: "abc1232",
    MessageAttributes: [
      {
        StringValue: "someval",
        DataType: "String"
      }
    ]
  }
  return topicMsg;
}
```

I have my SNS topic sending EmailJSON and the `MessageAttributes` is within `Message` string. I want to be able to have proper `MessageAttributes` so that I can filter them in the subscription to the topic correctly.